# My python if statement doesn't print the result

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator")

input("Enter a Word: ")

original = input()

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print(original)
else:
    print("empty")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input("Enter a Word: ")

original = input()
```

This is not how the `input()` function is meant to be used. You are actually asking the user for 2 inputs. You ignore the first one and only use the second one (which is probably empty).

Instead, ask for a single input and keep it.

```
print("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator")

original = input("Enter a Word: ")

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print(original)
else:
    print("empty")
```